# Not getting the Error Message in Validation using angular5

Tags: angular

Here is my code for client side Validation using Angularjs5.

```
<form class="col s12 white" #userRegistrationForm="ngForm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input class="validate" type="text" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.UserName" required>
            <label data-error="Required Field!">UserName</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.Password" required>
              <label>Password</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" name="Email" #Email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.Email">
              <label>Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName">
                <label>FirstName</label>
              </div>

              <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input type="text" name="LastName" #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.LastName">
                  <label>LastName</label>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <button class="btn-large btn-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
```

Am not getting the Error Message when validation is failed.Anyone please give a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to display the error message "Required Field!",when the UserName field is empty.                                                                  
 <label data-error="Required Field!">UserName</label>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <label *ngIf="UserName.errors.required">Required Field!</label>
```

Check documentation on how to use angular form-validation here:

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: It does n't works.If i use this line other fields are not displayed.